# Why $P_{L_0}P_L=P_{L_0}$ when $L_0 \subset L$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why $P_{L_0}P_L=P_{L_0}$ when $L_0 \subset L$?
It seems like a trivial one, but I want a logical (mathmatical) explanation.
For example, if $L=R(X)$ : range space of $X$ then $P_X=X(X'X)^{-1}X'$, so
so $P_{L_0}P_L=\dots$ somethinkg like this.

Comment: Hint: Consider a basis of $L_0$, and then extend it to the basis of $L$ and further that of the whole vector space.